# Android phone won't connect to eclipse

Tags: java, android, eclipse, mobile

I have an orange nivo or "coolpad" but i can't connect it to the eclipse.. it just doesn't recognise it any suggestions?

I've tried to turn USB debugging on the phone still the same thing.
I've tried to update drivers from Drivers Manager.
[image: My eclipse]
[image: My Drivers Manager]

Comment: I know you said you turned debugging on but did you make sure that the phone wasn't plugged in when you turned it on?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to update drivers with drivers who are in your SDK at :

```
\adt\sdk\extras\google
```

It's work for my devices

Comment: it just give me an error telling me that it can't be done and no details

Comment: Have you any device named "Android" in Devices Manager ?

Comment: now it works but it says application can be debugged on port 8100

Answer (score 0):

may be your Android ADB drivers didn't get installed properly. You can refer this [link](http://theunlockr.com/2009/10/06/how-to-set-up-adb-usb-drivers-for-android-devices/)

or you can try after market software like **PDAnet** which install all the mobile drivers including ADB drivers.

Answer (score 0):

Just download the latest drivers for your phone from the manufacturer website. And turn on usb debugging in the dev settings